# Validating email addresses through temporary mail message

Tags: c#, validation, email

I was given this project and have changed a lot of code on it, now I am going over the code to make sure that I know what everything does and can maintain it efficiently, and to make sure I want my name on it.

Here is the method they have been using to validate e-mail addresses from a textbox input.

```
private string ValidateEmailAddresses(string addressesIn)
{
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(addressesIn))
    {
        string[] allAddresses = addressesIn.Split(";,".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        foreach (string addy in allAddresses)
        {
            try
            {
                msg.To.Add(addy);
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            { }
        }
    }
    return msg.To.ToString();
}
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this task?

Comment: It rejects valid addresses like `"Smith, Jane"@example.com` (not that I’ve ever seen anyone use such an address, but I believe it is valid).

Comment: Not sure if it is valid or not but if a FormatException is being thrown then that's framework behavior, which means you'd be SOL trying to send an email to that address anyway.

Comment: Not sure if this is an answer or not, but using exceptions as a code path is an expensive proposition. Basically, the runtime has to collect a fair amount of information (the stack being the most expensive) for each `FormatException`. Thus, I would not use this in a performance-sensitive area of the application.

Comment: I think this is one of the smart way to validate and filter out non-complaint email format. A bit inefficient but it is only use on data entry, if it were to be use in a loop to validate thousands of emails then a regular expression match would me more appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Well, it really depends on why `addressesIn` is a string. If it's input from the user, as I suspect, it is a fine method.
- If I was to be a harsh critic I would ask why a method named "Validate" returns a string.
- I think if you rename the method to like "ScrubEmailAddresses" or "SanitizeEmailAddresses" and envision it in an app that lets a user input email addresses to send an email to, it's kind of nifty. Basically instead of a roll-your-own-validations approach this says "hey, let the framework do it for me!" by taking advantage of the fact that .NET will just throw a FormatException if you try to add an invalid address. It's a fairly decent server-side equivalent to a RegularExpressionValidator using the predefined email regex. I also agree with Mike McCaughan's comment mentioning there is a resource hit when having the framework throw an exception.

Comment: I don't think the latter part is harsh at all; it's a great question. As it stands, this method has an unfavorably high WTF factor given its small size and scope.

Comment: I think if you rename the method to like "ScrubEmailAddresses" or "SanitizeEmailAddresses" and envision it in an app that lets a user input email addresses to send an email to, it's kind of nifty. Basically instead of a roll-your-own-validations approach this says "hey, let the framework do it for me!" by taking advantage of the fact that .NET will just throw a FormatException if you try to add an invalid address. It's a fairly decent server-side equivalent to a RegularExpressionValidator.

Comment: that should be edited into your answer @moarboilerplate. that is a good point

Answer (score 2):

One option, you have, is to make the TextBox multiline and instruct the user to type one email address per line.  By changing your method to accept a string array, you won't need to split the string just pass in the Lines property of the TextBox:

```
private string ValidateEmailAddresses(string[] addressesIn)
{
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

    if (addressesIn.Length != 0)
    {

        foreach (string addy in addressesIn)
        {
            try
            {
                msg.To.Add(addy);
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            { }
        }
    }
    return msg.To.ToString();
}
```

A further thought, rather than returning the string of addresses, put this code in the Validate event handler for the TextBox.  Then in the Catch block build a multiline string of the failed email addresses to display in a MessageBox to prompt the user to fix or delete the offending lines.  Once all the addresses are validated, simply use the data in the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

As [icktoofay](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/28033/icktoofay) [points out](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/74706/validating-email-addresses-through-temporary-mail-message#comment135800_74706):

> It rejects valid addresses like `"Smith, Jane"@example.com`

Check out [this post](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx/) for an interesting explanation without having to actually read the RFC.

The problem is with this section of code

> addressesIn.Split(";,".ToCharArray() ...

As you are splitting on `;` and `,`, it will split on any quoted `;` or `,` characters within the email address local part such as the one found in the above email address.

With the exception of that, this is a good piece of code to find out if you have a *possibly* valid email address. Yes, control flow logic based on an exception is generally bad, however unless this is a massive bulk operation it will not cause anything more than a minor performance hit. At the end of the day, the only way to find out if it is truly valid is to send a message to it and ask the recipient to click a link containing a cryptographically secure random sequence. However, some anti-spam systems will [automatically follow links](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/66090/8340) in emails so this does not validate whether you have a human being at the other end, so you could get them to manually enter a random code instead on a form linked from the email.

To summarise, you need to find a method of splitting the email addresses without accidentally splitting on quoted sections. Yes, you'd be mad to purposely register the email address `"this;will,never,be;accepted;anywhere"@example.com` or to set one up for one of your employees with an address like this. However, we had a customer using one of our systems recently and they requested a change to the email validation routine as their customer had an employee with an email address like `David.O'leary@example.com` which our system was rejecting and they could not register.

This is why I like your approach of relying on the built in `MailAddress` object to validate, which as also suggested in the first comment in this article: [Don’t trust the .NET web forms email regex validator (or most others)](http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/11/dont-trust-net-web-forms-email-regex.html).

Comment: http://www.remote.org/jochen/mail/info/chars.html
Email Addresses don't allow `,` or `;` in them

Comment: @Malachi: That site shows `whether they can or should be allowed` not whether they are allowed by the specification. For `,` it states `RFC2822 allowes [sic] their use if they are inside double quotes` and for `;` it states `The semicolon could theoretically be used, but must be quoted`. [The spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-3.2.5) allows almost any character in a quoted string. Yes, you'd probably be mad to have these characters in your email address, but it does happen (we recently had to change a validation routine as one of our customer's user's had the `'` character).

Comment: I see. I should read more and scan less. I don't think I am going to worry about these corner cases because the addresses are going to be a select handful, this site is not open to the public.